# How to render a form 'n' number of times based on the dropdown selected integer in main Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

1.I have the below requirement in django to implement.

a)I have a main form with a few fields [text input fields,choice fields ]
b)Based on the user input on integer field from the dropdown box in a template,
i need to display few more fields waiting for the user input.
Ex:If user selected an integer :3
i need to display another form 3 times containing few fields [ text input fields,choice fields] in the same html django template.[Say it is SubForm1]

c) Again based on dropdown selection in subform1

i need to display few more fields waiting for the user input.
Ex:If user selected an integer :4
i need to display another form 3 times containing few fields [ text input fields,choice fields] in the same html django template.[Say it is SubForm2]

Screenshot is shown below.

How to accomplish this .Can some one please share if any tutorial or any similar post already done at any place or clarify this.
Basically i dont know much javascript/jquery .can we accomplish this only using django forms & templates with out using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to know is javascript and its library i.e jQuery. Trying to show something based on user input is a front-end task. I will give you a short explanation for this.

First you have to import jquery script.So in head tag of your html page. Add the following:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now comes the next part. of deciding what to do when user enters any value.Suppose you have an input field of number type with some id.

```
<input type="number" id="userInput" name="quantity">
```

Now you want to perform some action on the basis of entered value. So this will be the way

```
<script>
  var entered_value  = $("#userInput").val();
  if(entered_value === 4)
   {
      //perform some task
   }
 </script>
```

There are multiple tasks you can perform like appending,hiding,showing and removing an element etc. You have to learn some basic javascript and jQuery. Mozilla has made an excellent documentation. You can refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference . jQuery has its official website i.e https://jquery.com .I would suggest you to learn some basic javascript first. Then move on to jquery because jQuery is nothing but a javascript library. It basically provide user friendly and easier to read syntax methods.Under the hood it's all javascript. Rest you can search any topic on google and study about it.I hope this will help you.